# SOLR ERROR - cannot add core [beggining step] is there any good tutorial for this?

Tags: solr, solr9

Error:

```
 /opt/solr-9.4.0/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/core.properties : /opt/solr-9.4.0/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/core.properties
```

Whatever I try from the SOLR [documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/getting-started/tutorial-techproducts.html) to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zw4M4NGv-Rw) nothing works and I constantly have problems and errors. Is this really that hard to implement? This is my third day and this is really frustrating..... Apache server work on 8983 port but nothing else work.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Only apache server work on 8983 port"? What is the actual error message you're getting? What response do you get when you go to http://localhost:8983? What are you trying to do when you receive the error messages?

Comment: I mean that Apache server works. Now I grantend 777 permissions and the tutorial from documentation started to work. But I have new problem. 

When I run this command: 
bin/post -c techproducts example/exampledocs/* 

I get the following error: 

The bin/post script is deprecated in favour of the bin/solr post command. Please update your scripts.
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/update
SimplePostTool: Response: <p>
  Searching for Solr?<br/>
  You must type the correct path.<br/>
  Solr will respond.

Comment: What do you find if you go to `http://localhost:8983/solr` ? But are you using Apache Tomcat? (since you're talking about Apache server); Solr uses Jetty, not an Apache httpd

Comment: I can open SOLR admin on :8983 port.

Comment: Have you created the `techproducts` collection? Can you see it in the interface under collections?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, that was a problem. Now I have more problems, but that one was solved :)